# Windows 7 will not boot after OS-Uninstaller removal of Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

Before using OS-Uninstaller my system was:
- A fairly new Dell Precision M3800 laptop, 128 MB SSD, 1 TB rotating internal hard drive
- Windows 7 installed 
- Ubuntu 14.04 installed (these as dual boot)

After using OS-Uninstaller (using an Ubuntu 14.04 bootable USB flash drive) to get rid of the installed Ubuntu 14.04, I cannot boot Windows 7.  The error message given is:  "An operating system wasn't found.  Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system."  (There are, as far as I know, no such drives.)

Using the same USB bootable I have run Boot-Repair, but I still have the same errors.

Using Gparted and Nautilus, I have verified that the main Windows data repository on the 1 TB drive (which was about 750 GB) exists, seems to be intact, seems to have my data.  I believe the partition which held the Windows 7 OS on the SSD is also intact, as /dev/sdb3, but nautilus does not mount it by default and I have not yet tried.  (Afraid to do further damage.)

The Boot-Repair report URL is:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/12122184/

How can I recover from this?

Answer (score 2):

Grub is the boot loader for linux os including Ubuntu.
You can edit grub boot loader and set operating systems you want to boot with different options. You may refer following link for further reading

[Grub boot loader (Grub 2)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Otherwise you have deleted Ubuntu and now you have only Windows 7 you can 
edit boot.ini file using botting with any live OS like CentOS or else using other Live OS.

Here is the sample boot.ini

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect
This is a sample of the above Boot.ini file with a previous installation of Windows 2000 on a separate partition.

[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINNT="Windows 2000 Professional" /fastdetect
```

[Sample Boot.ini File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289022)